# Security in Selenium 2?

Tags: json, security, selenium, selenium-grid

I was asking myself if Selenium has any possibilities to secure the communication in Selenium Grid for example. As far as I know Selenium communicates via JSON and Selenese commands. But it is not encrypted. Are there any possibilities to encrypt the communication?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick hack: make an ssh tunnel.

Forward remote server's port 4444 as a local port using following ssh command:

ssh user@remotesrv -L 4444:127.0.0.1:4444

Now when you connect to your local port 4444, it actually connects to your server's port 4444 on a secure link. Refer to this [link](http://www.debianadmin.com/howto-use-ssh-local-and-remote-port-forwarding.html) for tutorial.

Afterwards, just open the remote web driver as you normally do.

This will now be on a secure link.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to run your own SSL proxy in front of the hub and the nodes.  It is presumed that you aren't publicly exposing your grid.